# Can I use those TO-220 heatsinks with a TO-126 package?

Tags: transistors, heatsink

[image]

The TO-126 component is this : https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/bd679-datasheet.pdf

Dimensions for heatsink : 19.7 mm - 14.8mm - 9.7mm

I wonder can I mount this TO-220 heatsinks to BD679 or not. The total power dissipation on the transistors will be around 700-800 mW average with 1.3-1.4 Watt peaks for like .5 miliseconds, repetitively.

Comment: Probably the biggest reason you couldn't would be if it takes a screw larger than 3mm in diameter (see the transistor datasheet).  The best way to find out for sure would be take a mechanical drawing of the heat sink and draw the transistor package on top of it, with the transistor hole centered on the heat sink hole.  If it looks like it'll fit -- you're in.  Alternately, if you want to be all 21st-century about it, you could do it in 3D mechanical modeling software, but if that's **all** you need to do it's better to do it on paper.

Comment: @TimWescott although I asked here, I have no choice actually. I cannot find a TO-126 heatsink in the borders of country. I have ordered those TO-220 heatsinks, which also came from china to a local supplier, so no part number or dahasheet for heatsink. If it don't fit, then I don't know how to dissipate that power.

Comment: If you're concerned about the amount of power they'll dissipate, look to see if you can find a heat sink calculator on the web.  If you're worried about actual physical fit, try them when they come in.  If you can get your hands on aluminum sheet, you can **make** a heat sink by bending a bunch of "U" shaped pieces, putting heat sink goo between them, and bolting them together onto the transistor.

Comment: I'm almost certain that if the question is "I need an TO-126 heat sink for my single BD679", then the answer is "well build your own darlington array from two discrete transistors for which you actually do get heat sinks instead"; that thing is ancient, anyway. Since you have access to opamps, a simple NPN-buffered opamp amplifier would be an easy alternative that gives you all the freedom you need to select transistors that you get heat sinks for.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I also bought few TIP41/42C power npn/pnps. If I cannot handle the power dissipation on the darlingtons, I will then try to use that configuration. I am trying to build a class A-B amp to drive a speaker, so I am not sure "a simple npn-buffered opamp" helps me.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what were you referring as ancient?

Comment: The BD679. Of course, the TIP41 and TIP42 are even more ancient. You need to lay off the 1970's hobbyist magazines, or wherever you get these part recommendations from.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the thing is, I don't know how to find newer ones, I searched on the web after your comment, and can't find a complementary pair. Can you advice me some models?

Comment: have you looked at websites like digikey.com?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I have but don't know with what parameters should I filter to get good ones. I don't need extensive properties, 2A Ic and 15V Vce is far enough for me, for example.

Comment: so, fill these in!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mean, what makes those parts obsolete, rather than being produced 50 years ago, is there a reason, in what aspects TIP41/42 worse than newer models, which specs of them make them unuseful? So I restrict those specifications.

Comment: While the PN junction largely stayed the same principle, physically, the gains, the way they are contacted, the design of the enclosing hull, the purities and most of all: the tolerances have made great leaps. You'll find that you can build better amplifiers with fewer stages and hence lower power consumption, lower heat production and lower noise if you can use more reliably higher-gain transistors.

Answer (score 2):

This heatsink for TO-220 packages is designed to be mounted vertically on a printed circuit board with the device fastened to the heatsink with a M3 screw which has a major diameter limit for the screw 2.98 mm and nut minimum diam =3.00 mm

I verified the 3mm thread size on an identical part on the web (I lost link, cant you search?)

TO-247=TO-126 have the same hole size of 3.60 mm +/-0.05

Quick sketch ... Thermal grease  needed

[image]

[image]

Comment: that TO126 has a hole size of 3 to 3.2 mm.  if the screw is indeed M3 it should just barely work. (3.6 is for TO220)

Comment: you probabl;y need to countersink that threaded hole a little so that the TO126 can sit flat on the heatsink.

Comment: Check again Jasen

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like the screw that fits in the hole of the heatsink is too large for a TO-126. If this is the case, you can still use it by drilling a new hole of the right size in the other end of the heatsink. It will work just as well "upside down".

Comment: the answer below states the opposite, or I understand it wrong.

Comment: I think it will be clear when you have both parts in hand. By upside down I meant with the mounting tab sticking up rather than down into the PCB. A 126 case is smaller than a 220 so the new hole could be near the center and the leads could stick out either end.